# Insterting old data with Unique ID conflicts in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

I am working on a midsize website that recently went through an upgrade. During that upgrade, segments of the database weren't carried over. Now the new website has been in production for over a month, and my boss wants the missing bits to be incorporated back in.

There are several sets of tables, with Unique auto assigned primary key IDs, that I need to transfer. There are already conflicting keys in the production database, so I cant just insert all my rows.

I am think of just adding a base number (maybe 10000) to all the primary keys in my old data. This will ensure there are no conflicts with the stuff already in the new database, but I am not sure how MySQL will react. I also keep wondering if there is a better and/or standard way to accomplish this.

What is the best way to insert my data?

Comment: Can you not just add all information but the key ID column, letting it receive a new ID automatically?

Comment: Need to preserve the relations, so I need to update the ID both in the main table and the table referencing it, and keep them in sync.

Comment: I agree with AlwaysLearning, you could write a migration script, which would transfer all data and take care of relations - so you would have all data properly transfered and no messing up with auto increment needed

Comment: @Laimoncijus not sure how a migration script like that would work, never used something like that before. Totally interested, could you elaborate?

Comment: In theory its quite simple: a script which reads out from old DB records one by one, including all associated records across all involved tables - then on new DB you insert them, reading out new IDs and link records properly with new IDs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to my question, a migration script is the way to go. This can be an actual migration script for your DB platform or a script in the language of your choice that reads from 1 database and adds the data to the 2nd one.

Adding a "base number" like I describe in my question is a bad idea, and can lead to error both during the transfer in the future.

I ended up resolving the conflicting IDs manually, which were in fact due to a previous developer trying to add a base number to all IDs during an earlier migration & instead introducing bad duplicate data to the database.